# How do you add a bootstrap icon to an canvas, using javascript? If there is a way

Tags: javascript, icons, bootstrapping

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
     ctx.setAttribute("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-time");
```

but also;

```
    var icon = document.createElement("span");

    icon.className ="glyphicon glyphicon-time";
    this.appendChild(icon);
```

Comment: Do you mean draw the icon in the canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [html2canvas.js](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

The following code may help you:

HTML

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span>

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

JS

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector('.glyphicon'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var myCanvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
        var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image;

        img.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        };

        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();

        document.querySelector('.glyphicon').style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7moorthi/qpyj02k8/

Here I have used the [html2canvas.js](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to render the html code to a canvas which will dynamically create and return an in memory canvas element (which you can append to some elements if you want). I don't want to use the dynamically created canvas since it will cause some problems when i want to update the canvas content. So I just get the dataurl of the canvas, converted it as an image object and drawn it to my already existing canvas element.

**EDIT:**

As [@Patrick Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560593/patrick-evans) mentioned, you can directly use `fillText()` method to render gylphicon into canvas.

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'glyphicon';
    src: url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
        url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
        url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
        url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
        url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

JS

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = '20px glyphicon';

ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(0x2a), 10, 50);
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7moorthi/qpyj02k8/3/

To get the char code for a icon use [gylphicon cheat sheet](http://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/). Click the copy dropdown below each icon on the cheat sheet and click on **Unicode HTML Entity**. Now the unicode value will be copied to your clipboard. It will look something like this `&#x2a;`. Replace `&#` with `0` and remove `;` to get the char code.

Comment: You do not need html2canvas to draw the gylphicon into the canvas. You can simply use the drawText function since the gylphicon is a font (after setting the canvas' font ie `ctx.font = "some font name"` of course)

Comment: Okay for the most part it worked, the fromCharCode bit works great, but only for unicode entities that do not have the e within the code.  I am trying to get 0xe023 to work correctly.  In JSFiddle, it produces the clock just fine....in my site, it produces a wierd F type symbol (seriously never seen it before haha).  Any ideas why this might be happening.  I have fonts loaded into visual studio and the url paths to glyphicons in the css style page.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment as lack of reputation but to answer your question about why you can't draw anything that has an e in the hex code. It's because you need to use the font

```
ctx.font = '12px glyphicons halflings';
```

rather than just glyphicon.