# How to draw an ionic icon in a HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas, ionic3

I am developping an Ionic3 Application, I am using a html5 canvas for some complex graphic drawing. I need to draw an existant ionic icon. 
So, how can I draw it inside my canvas with typescript?

Comment: what do you mean with draw an icon, you want to add html element like this : <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>

Comment: yes but inside the canvas

Comment: may this help you : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570801/how-to-draw-font-awesome-icons-onto-html-canvas

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976961/how-do-you-add-a-bootstrap-icon-to-an-canvas-using-javascript-if-there-is-a-wa